# GET photos from Facebook Event wall (including public photos of not-friends)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-api, facebook-java-sdk, facebook-events

I have been trying to issue a GET request to Facebook using the graph API to retrieve all the photos posted to an event wall. I want to have them so they can be shown like a "living scrapbook" on the TV screen.

I issued a GET request to /EVENT_ID/photos but all I receive are the photos posted by me and my friends. Anyone photo poste by a someone who isn't my friend simply doesn't show up.

I issued a GET request to /EVENT_ID/feed and I do receive all the posts but photos show up like this:

```
{
  "id": "487778861276668_487912981263256",
  "from": {
    "name": "Nicu Tinar",
    "id": "100005604480588"
  },
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Te Noiembrie",
        "start_time": "2013-11-14T19:30:00+0200",
        "timezone": "Europe/Bucharest",
        "location": "Piața Unirii",
        "id": "487778861276668"
      }
    ]
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/487778861276668/posts/487912981263256"
    },
    {
      "name": "Like",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/487778861276668/posts/487912981263256"
    }
  ],
  "privacy": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "type": "status",
  "created_time": "2013-03-27T20:50:37+0000",
  "updated_time": "2013-03-27T20:50:37+0000",
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }
},
```

(Don't worry this is a fake test post and event)

As you can see the existance of the post is acknowledged but I am not given a picture URL.

What's going on? How can I get the picture from this event-wallpost?

Answer (score 0):

Due to privacy, I don't think it's possible to do it through the API.